# Ionic build taking too much time 300s every time 100s+

Tags: npm, ionic3, node-modules, sourceforge-appscript

command: `ionic serve`

Every time it's taking more than 100s and last time it was 300s.
[image]
these are my dev dependencies.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.2",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "^10.1.0",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2",
    "ws": "3.3.2"
  },
```

this is my system configuration
[image]

How to reduce this build time.